# Need Help in converting c# code to powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I am having a problem to convert this **c# code** to **powershell script**

```
var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8181");
server.Start(socket =>
  {
    socket.OnOpen = () => Console.WriteLine("Open!");
    socket.OnClose = () => Console.WriteLine("Close!");
    socket.OnMessage = message => socket.Send(message);
  });
```

I am already loading the related dll in the memory and particularly need help understanding and converting this block of code.

```
server.Start(socket =>
  {
    socket.OnOpen = () => Console.WriteLine("Open!");
    socket.OnClose = () => Console.WriteLine("Close!");
    socket.OnMessage = message => socket.Send(message);
  });
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: I have already given the C# code above, which needs conversion to powershell script. I apologize if I am not able to communicate my question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already imported your types, this is what you can do. Not sure it will work, since I don't know what exact types of parameters you have.

```
$server = New-Object -TypeName WebSocketServer -ArgumentList "ws://localhost:8181"
$server.Start([Action[Socket]] { 
    param([Socket]$s) 
    $s.OnOpen = [Action] { Write-Host "Open!" } 
    $s.OnClose = [Action] { Write-Host "Close!" } 
    $s.OnMessage = [Action[string]] {
        param([string]$message)
        $s.Send($message)
    }

})
```